# GoCardless and one-off payments

Tags: civicontribute

I understand GoCardless can accept a one-off payment but it looks as if the extension written for Civi may not yet have any way to connect to the GoCardless one-off bill resource. Does anyone know if that's the case?

We had been trying to set up two contribution pages (membership options): one for recurring monthly payments and the other for annual, non-recurring payments. For the annual payments, on the amounts tab, we did try leaving the checkbox for Recurring Contributions unticked but naturally, on testing, GoCardless throws an error: Interval length can't be blank - Interval unit must be "day", "week" or "month".

Any thoughts? Should we just use another payment processor for the non-recurring payments?

Answer (score 2):

From @kakajaran's 26 November comment on [veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.gocardlessdd#5](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.gocardlessdd/issues/5), it seems at this time the extension is expected to work with recurring payments only.

I would suggest [filing an issue on the project's Github](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.gocardlessdd) to signal that you'd like support for this, then either reaching out to the extension developers directly or finding other ways to support the fix you require (eg by submitting a patch directly, or sponsoring work to make it happen).

Comment: Thanks, Chris, yes, I saw that one and I read it that way too. I can see there's a GoCardless_Bill class (lib/GoCardless/Bill.php) in there so it's probably on the ToDo list :-)
I've filed an issue on Github.